# Is there a SQL query to get SSRS up time or start time?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm looking for a way to determine how long SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) has been running using an SQL query.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's just a reporting tool.  I don't think it matters how long it's been running.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to determine how long the instance of SQL Server has been running
[How to check SQL Server uptime](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3d7aa13d-61a7-48d2-ada6-2398b31feb39/how-to-check-sql-server-uptime-through-tsql)

```
USE master;

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @crdate DATETIME, @hr VARCHAR(50), @min VARCHAR(5)

SELECT @crdate = crdate
FROM sysdatabases
WHERE NAME = 'tempdb'

SELECT @hr = (DATEDIFF(mi, @crdate, GETDATE())) / 60

IF ((DATEDIFF(mi, @crdate, GETDATE())) / 60) = 0
    SELECT @min = (DATEDIFF(mi, @crdate, GETDATE()))
ELSE
    SELECT @min = (DATEDIFF(mi, @crdate, GETDATE())) - ((DATEDIFF(mi, @crdate, GETDATE())) / 60
            ) * 60

PRINT 'SQL Server "' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME')) + '" is Online for the past ' + 
    @hr + ' hours & ' + @min + ' minutes'

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
        WHERE program_name = N'SQLAgent - Generic Refresher'
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'SQL Server is running but SQL Server Agent <<NOT>> running'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'SQL Server and SQL Server Agent both are running'
END
```

Comment: D'oh!  This show how long the host has been running but not SSRS. :(

Comment: So are you talking about SSRS which requires SQL Server?  Or do you actually mean an SSRS _report_ ?

Comment: Just the SSRS the service.

Comment: @NitroxDM - I've seen methods for determining _if_ the service is running, but not the duration of how long.  I look at it as if the SQL Server I have it installed on is up then so are my other services, but since I have no real need to know that's probably why that works for me.

Comment: I need to know how long the service has been up... I'm looking at parsing the windows event logs at this point.